# Generic way to list installed packages using Ansible

Tags: linux, shell, ansible

Right now in my current setup I am using Ansible with CentOs hosts.
One of the tasks contains the following line:

```
command: yum list installed somepackagename
```

As seen above the task will only work for hosts which support `yum` , but what if I want to run it on Ubuntu or some other Linux distribution?
After researching a bit online I found out that there is a generic package manager called `package`. With this I install/uninstall packages without worrying about the underlying hosts but not do something like `list` them as seen above.
Is there any module or any way I could achieve this in a generic way without creating multiple `when`s?

Answer (score 0):

Q: **"*Generic way to list installed packages using Ansible*"**

A: Use module [package_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html). The module returns facts in *ansible_facts.packages*

```yaml
- name: Gather the package facts
  package_facts:
- name: Print the package facts
  debug:
    var: ansible_facts.packages
```

---

Q: **"*There is a generic package manager called package ... install/uninstall packages without worrying about the underlying hosts*"**

A: An option of how not to "worry about the underlying hosts" completely is to include OS-specific packages in the variables. For example:

```yaml
    - name: vars
      include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
      with_first_found:
        - files:
            - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}.yml"
            - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
            - "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
            - "default.yml"
          paths: '{{ role_path }}/vars'
```