# Import variables from yaml file in ansible

Tags: ansible, roles

I am trying to import variables from a yaml file and use them in a role however I am trying to import the variables in a way that any any task file i import in the role can also use the same variable without any problem. So in simple words i am trying to create a kind of repo for variables that multiple roles or tasks files can use and the value can be preserved. the code i found from the documentation is:

```
  include_vars:
    dir: /projects/Variable_files
    files_matching: 
    - default.yml 
    - debian.yml
    name: default_vars
```

but I am getting this error:

> ERROR! 'include_vars' is not a valid attribute for a Play. The error appears to be in '/projects/wordpress.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
>   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dash `-` is missing. Correct syntax is

```
- include_vars:
    dir: /projects/Variable_files
    files_matching: '^(.*).yml$'
    name: default_vars
```

In addition to this, the parameter `files_matching` is a string with regular expression. For example `^(.*).yml$` to match all files with the extension `yml`. See [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task).

It's possible to use [first_found](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/first_found.html#first-found-return-first-file-found-from-list) to select a file from a list. For example, see [Generic way to list installed packages using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333097/generic-way-to-list-installed-packages-using-ansible/).

---

Despite the fact that the parameter `files_matching` should be a string the list works too

```
- include_vars:
    dir: /projects/Variable_files
    files_matching: 
    - default.yml 
    - debian.yml
    name: default_vars
```

Comment: thank you. This is what is not giving me an error:
- name: Add the var file
  include_vars:
    dir: /projects/Variable_files
    files_matching: 
    - default.yml 
    - debian.yml
    name: default_vars

Comment: But this doesn't satisfy what i want. I want ansible to import vars as soon as the role kicks in and these vars can be used anywhere in the role execution and any task file called using import_task statement can use the variables for example i am trying to prompt the user password for sql password and that value should stay the same during the entire execution and can be shared to the external task files during execution too

Comment: See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).